# How to force BackgroundWorker to continue running when app is closed?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I don't know how much about BackgroundWorker, and I have a problem. My BackgroundWorker is correctly running to completion when my app is open, but if my app is closed the BackgroundWorker does not complete.

Is there any way to force a BackgroundWorker to continue running when my app is closed, rather than the BackgroundWorker terminating?

Answer (score 2):

Any task launched by your application will stop executing when your app is closed, and there's nothing you can do against that (well, there's a few very specific exceptions, like geolocation apps).

If you need to run code while your app is closed, you need to use a background agent. Note that those agents have a few limitations, especially in memory usage, and can run only for a few seconds every 30 minutes.

Comment: Is there any way to run Background agents without Extended Task(will be add in WMAppManifest.xml).

Comment: @user2782709 As far as I know, no. Is editing the manifest an issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Background Agent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx